# pyqt popup window not displaying properly

Tags: python, button, pyqt, popupwindow

I have created two different pyqt windows, and within one of them, by pressing a button, it should bring up another smaller window. While my code does pretty much exactly what I just dais it should do, there is a problem with the way the smaller popup window is displayed.

This is my code for displaying the windows and the button functionality:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from EnterprisePassport import Ui_StudentEnterprisePassport
from Session_tracker import Ui_Session_tracker

class StudentEnterprisePassport(Ui_StudentEnterprisePassport):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.sessionTracker_btn.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        self.window2 = None

    def handleButton(self):
        if self.window2 is None:
            self.window2 = Session_tracker(self)
            self.window2.show()

class Session_tracker(Ui_Session_tracker):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = StudentEnterprisePassport()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I can still use the functions within the window, but I can't move it, or close it, and there is no title bar. Have I done something wrong within my code for the popup window to appear like this?

Edit:

Original Session tracker window: [Original window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQqkj.png)
Popup session tracker window: [Popup window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H01cZ.png)

Comment: The popup window is given the main window as parent, I think it is the problem. Do `self.window2 = Session_tracker()` instead.

Comment: Or make it a `QDialog` instead of a `QWidget`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to show the other widget in it's own window, it has to be a `QMainWindow` or a `QDialog`.

One option, if you don't want to convert your existing `Session_tracker` to a `QDialog`, is to just wrap it in a `QDialog`

```
def handleButton(self):
    if self.window2 is None:
        self.window2 = QtGui.QDialog(self)
        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.window2.setLayout(lay)
        self.session_tracker = Session_tracker(self.window2)
        lay.addWidget(self.session_tracker)
        self.window2.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, I've used your edit and added it to my code, however I am facing another issue now. The popup window is displaying differently from the original, and for some reason, the columns displayed within the original window are now gone in the popup window. I have added screenshots of the two windows to the question. I haven't edited the code for the Session tracker window, so why is it that it changes it when I open it though a popup window?

Comment: One is a `QMainWIndow`, the other is a `QDialog`, that is why the windows are different.  If the columns aren't there, then they're not in your UI file.  The original window and the popup dialog are two different widgets -- StudentEnterprisePassport and SessionTrackers -- I wouldn't expect them to look the same.

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault. When I created the UI, I made them both as QWidget. I realised my mistake and changed that now, thank you.